# acceleration of water when it travels through garden hose

Tags: fluid-dynamics

How to derive average acceleration of water as it travels through nozzle of garden hose.  Suggest some assumptions  for better understanding

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please be clear about what you are asking so that the community can help you. Provide sufficient details (figures, variables to use , the quantity you want to compute etc.) and your attempt or ideas regarding solving the problem.

Comment: This question shows no research effort, and no attempt to solve the problem or identify the difficulties in trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The average acceleration of the water is equal to the rate of change of momentum within the nozzle.  This is equal to the mass flow rate times the exit velocity minus the inlet velocity.